# Integrate Azure Mobile Services in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, azure, cross-platform, azure-mobile-services

By the time I'm writing this, I'm working on a Xamarin cross-platform app (iOS,Android and Windows Phone), using Azure Mobile Services. There is interest of also developing Mac OS X version of this app.

Is there a way to use the Azure for the OS X app, because I can't find anything on the web? Please, be descriptive as possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently Xamarin.Mac support in Mobile Services.  If you look here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/tree/master/sdk) you will see there is a Xam.iOS, Android, and Forms project.

You can add a feature request for Xam.Mac, or make an open PR that adds in a Xam.Mac project.  I'd assume the main PCL component will work and its just a matter of adding the Mac specific wrappers where needed.  I'm not sure how much dev work that would actually entail though to say if its feasible or not.